# UIkit.modal.alert then chaining many functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, uikit, es6-promise, getuikit

I have a uikit alert, I want to click OK button in the alert then doing many chaining things following the order.

```
UIkit.modal.alert('test')
   .then(() => {
     // blah blah 1
      this.httpClient('url1').get().subscribe(data => {
      this.field1 = data;
       });
   })
   .then(() => {
     // blah blah 2
       this.updateUi(this.field1);
   })
  .then(() => {
     // blah blah 3
     this.httpClient('url3').post({body: this.detail}).subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
     });
   })
  .then(() => {
     // blah blah 4
     this.anotherField = 'newValue';
  });
```

However the chaining is not working well. It seems sometimes it run the `blah blah 4` first then run `blah blah 1` or other random orders.

I use `uikit 3.03`

Also I am okay with js alert rather than uikit alert by the way.

**UPDATE:**

Per comments, I create a demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-wc5ahn

Comment: Can you provide more code with the actual implementation? Promises inherently should not work out of order in the way you're describing.

Comment: @dillon, something like my updated. In the blahs, some are asynchronously, some are synchronously. Now I want them all run with the order by many `then` chaining.

Comment: Ah okay that is the issue, you have asynchronous operations that are not returning promises.. You want the httpClient calls to return promises so you can truly chain all of your calls

Comment: So I guess that either I have to convert the asynchronous operations to promises or I don't use `then` at all but following the principle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're mixing promises with other types of asynchronous operations. You could just do all promises to easily chain all async operations.

```js
const get = url => new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.httpClient(url)
            .get()
            .subscribe(resolve);
})
const post = (url, body) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.httpClient(url)
            .post({ body })
            .subscribe(resolve);
})

UIkit.modal.alert("test")
    .then(() => get("url1"))
    .then(dataFromUrl1 => {
        this.field1 = dataFromUrl1;
        this.updateUi(this.field1);
    })
    .then(() => post("url3", { body: this.detail }))
    .then(() => {
        // blah blah 4
        this.anotherField = "newValue";
    });
```

Example of working order of operation where UIkit.modal.alert() is returning a promise.

```js
const get = url => new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("GETTING");
    resolve();
})
const post = (url, body) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("POSTING");
    resolve();
})

console.log('opening modal');
UIkit.modal.alert("test")
    .then(() => get("url1"))
    .then(dataFromUrl1 => {
        console.log("finished getting :)");
    })
    .then(() => post("url3", { body: this.detail }))
    .then(() => {
        console.log("finished posting");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.0.3/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.0.3/dist/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.0.3/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE** given stackblitz link..

Your current implementation is:

```js
const t = UIkit.modal
      .alert("test")
      .then(() =>
        get("url1").then(() => {
          this.http.get<Kafein[]>(this.url).subscribe(data => {
            this.httpData = data;
            console.log(data[0]);
          });
        })
      )
      .then(() => post("url3", { body: "detail" }));
```

The problem is subtle yet not all the uncommon.. You are nesting chains when you do not need to. You can just chain without the nesting as such:

```js
const t = UIkit.modal
      .alert("test")
      .then(() => get("url1"))
      .then(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get<Kafein[]>(this.url).subscribe(data => {
            this.httpData = data;
            console.log(data[0]);
            resolve();
          });
      }))
      .then(() => post("url3", { body: "detail" }));
```

Comment: I think that the promise part works well if without alert. It seems that it `UIkit.modal.alert` doesn't support `then` function. The happened was it run promise first then in the middle time pop up alert window. What I want is to run the alert first, click Okay button then run promises.

Comment: I've just read up on the documentation for UIkit version 3.03 and UIkit.modal.alert(..) absolutely does return a promise and the above is working as I believe you've described you want.

Can you update you initial request with what you have not that is not working? I'd love to try from my side to get a better understanding.

Comment: I can't find the link. Would you please mind provide the link of `alert` document?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it is a bug of uikit?

Comment: I'm quite certain it's not a bug in uikit. I've just confirmed that it is working with the example updated in my response. This means that something else must be causing the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211896/discussion-between-hello-and-dillon).

Comment: @Hello - any update on whether or not you've got this working? Were you able to see the snippet in my response working?

Comment: The thing is that your code doesn't have `this.httpClient('url').subscribe()`  in the then parts. I have it in the last then block. It sometimes run first. It is wild.

Comment: Please update the original post and put your new code? or share a codesandbox. That is not how it should be working. If the subscribe is truly in the last then block, that should be the last thing to run. It might be a syntactical misunderstanding that can be simply fixed.

Comment: mate, can you give access to source code please. I can only see the bundled javascript from the link you've posted..

Comment: actually just found it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/call-http-request-in-angular-6-wc5ahn

Comment: I've found your problem and am updating my response to point it out..

Comment: It is almost there, one more question. Can I put resolve() in complete part of an observable?